# Global variable placement for functions

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm currently taking a JavaScript class and have the following assignment:
"Design a JavaScript program that asks the user for two numbers, and then sends these two numbers as arguments to four arithmetic functions: addition, multiplication, division, and modulus... The functions should return the values to the calling module, where they're displayed."

```
    <body>
        <h1>Number Functions</h1>
        <!-- FORM START -->
        <form name="Numbers">
        First number:
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="number1"/>
        <br/>
        Second Number:
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="number2"/>
        <p/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showInfo()"/>
        <p/>
        <textarea rows="8" colspan="150" name="info" readonly="true" value=""></textarea>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showInfo() {
    // Declare and get variables
    var firstNumber = parseFloat(document.Numbers.number1.value); // first number
    var secondNumber = parseFloat(document.Numbers.number2.value); // second number


    // Four mathematical functions
    function add(num1, num2) { 
    var sum = num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1+num2).toFixed(2) + "\n";
    return sum;
    }
    function multiply(num1, num2) {
    var product = num1 + " \u00d7 " + num2 + " = " + (num1*num2).toFixed(2) + "\n";
    return product;
    }
    function divide(num1, num2) {
    var dividend = num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + (num1/num2).toFixed(2) + "\n";
    return dividend;
    }
    function modulus(num1, num2) {
    var surplus = num1 + " % " + num2 + " = " + (num1%num2).toFixed(2);
    return surplus;
    }

    var total = add(firstNumber,secondNumber) + multiply(firstNumber,secondNumber) + divide(firstNumber,secondNumber) + modulus(firstNumber,secondNumber);

    document.Numbers.info.value = total;
    // I need this function to get the results from the four above and put them in the textarea!
    }

</script>
</body>
```

I'm not exactly sure how I should be getting the results of these four functions and displaying the results, but I do suspect that a lot of the reasons my code isn't working is because of incorrect variable placement. This is an online class and the textbook is horrible! So if you could point me in the right direction (or multiple correct directions), that'd be great.

Comment: First, to use your function you need to invoke it. There are 4 ways to do that but in your case you can just invokel it with the `()` so its should be `add() + multiply() + divide() + modulus()`. Second, in your case, you expect your function to return a value so you need to have a `return` statement like `return num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1+num2).toFixed(2);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with this.

1. First, you shouldn't set num1 and num2 at the very top of your script. They will start out not set, so you should retrieve them in your showInfo function.
2. You aren't returning anything from your functions, which you should be
3. You aren't actually calling your functions in showInfo, you are coercing them to a string, and thus seeing odd behavior.
4. It sounds like you should be passing in num1 and num2, not relying on a global variable to access them. You need to pass them and have each function accept two variables.

Try something like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLb1vzrb/

```
// Four mathematical functions
function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2).toFixed(2);
}

function multiply(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + " \u00d7 " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
}

function divide(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + (num1 / num2).toFixed(2);
}

function modulus(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + " % " + num2 + " = " + (num1 % num2).toFixed(2);
}

function showInfo() {
    // Declare and get variables
    var num1 = parseFloat(document.Numbers.number1.value); // first number
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.Numbers.number2.value); // second number

  document.Numbers.info.value = add(num1, num2) + multiply(num1, num2) + divide(num1, num2) + modulus(num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just posted my updated code. Can you give me any more advice?

Comment: Not really for this problem. If I've answered your question, can you mark my answer as accepted?